# Android NotificationListenerService with Dagger-Hilt

Tags: android, service, dagger-hilt

The *NotificationListenerService* stopped functioning after I implemented Dagger_Hilt on my project. Wonder I'm doing some wrong implementation

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class NotificationReader : NotificationListenerService() {
        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
        }
    }

    <service android:name=".services.NotificationReader"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
    </service>

    @HiltAndroidApp
    class StatusReaderApp : Application() {}
```